# update vault secret using terraform

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to push terraform variable to vault using this recource

```
resource "vault_generic_secret" "secret" {
  path = "mxv/terraform/machines/test"

  data_json =  <<EOT
{
  "ip": "aws_instance.app_server.public_ip"
}
EOT
}
```

but in vault pushed variable name not value. Is there any way to push value from terraform to vault?

Comment: You need to use interpolation syntax: `"${aws_instance.app_server.public_ip}".

Comment: in EOT may be you do not need ". Just: ${aws_instance.app_server.public_ip}